# Dynamoose aggregae MAX

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamoose

My sql query is look like

```
SELECT cate_id, MAX( book_price)
FROM book_mast
GROUP BY cate_id;
```

I'm new to dynamodb but I'm trying to translate the previous query into dynamoose query.

Comment: How you access your data in DynamoDB is entirely dependent on how you store your data.  In other words, you need to store your data to support your application access patterns.  Since you did not define how you are storing your data, we cant really answer your question.  This is a common mistake when just starting out with Ddb.  Can you describe what your data looks like so we can help with this access pattern?